# Rearranging strings in numerical order

Tags: bash, scripting, text-formatting, bioinformatics

I have multiple text files like this:

```
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_59M
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCGCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCAGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_62M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_53M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_54M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGACCCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_55M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_57M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_58M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_60M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_61M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
```

I want to order both the header (everything after ">") and its corresponding sequence in the following line so that they end up being in ascending numerical order like this:

```
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_53M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_54M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGACCCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_55M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_57M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_58M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_59M
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCGCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCAGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_60M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_61M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_62M
ATGCCTGTCACTCTCCCGCGCCTGGCGTTGCTAGGTGCCCTGCTCTTCCCTGTGGCTGCCGCCTGGGCCGCCGAGCTCCGCCTGGAACTGCCGGGGGGCACGCAGACCTGGAGCAGCGAAGAACTGCTCAGGCATCCGCAGGCCCGCGACCTGGACATCCCGGCCGACGTCGCCTACCGCCGGAACATGCGCTACCGCGCCGTGCCACTGGCGGCCTTGTTGAAAGGCGTGCATCCCGAAGACCATTTGCAGGCCGTGGCCAGCGATGGCTTCGCCGCCGAGTTGCCGGCCGCCCCGCTGCTCGCCGAACAGGGCTCGCAAGCCTGGCTGGCGATAGAGGATCCGCAGCGCCCCTGGCCGCCGTTGGGCGCCGGCAAGCCGTCCGCCGGGCCGTTCTATCTGGTCTGGAGCAAACCCGAGGAAAAACGCATCGGTCCGGAGCAATGGCCCTTCCAGGTCGTCCGCATCCGCTATCAGCCCCCTCTGGCCGAACGCTTCCCGGCCCTGCTGCCGGCCGCCGACGCCAGCGCGGAAGTGCGCGCCGGCTTCGCCGTGTTCCAGAAGAACTGCCTGGCCTGCCACCGTCTCAACGGTGCCGGCGACGCCCAGTTCGGCCCGGACCTGAACCTGCCGTACAACCCCACCGAGTACTTCCAGCCGCAATTCCTCTCCCGCTACATCCGCGACCCGCAGGCGCTGCGGCAATGGCCACAGGCGAAAATGCCGGCGTTCCCGGAACGGGTGATCGACGACCAGGAGTTGCGCCAGTTGATCGGCTACTTGCGCCACATGGCCGGCCGCAAGGCGGGCGCGGCCGGCTGA
```

*Sometimes there are missing numbers, like 56M in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's/ /\n/' <(sort -n <(sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /' in.txt))
```

**Explanations:**

- The `sed -e 'N;s/\n/ /' in.txt` parts, joining each two lines together with single space
- The `sort -n` part, performing numerical sort
- Then `sed -e 's/ /\n/'`, we are spliting the line to two separate lines according to the single space between.
- The `-i` will write the changes into the input file inplace, using `-i.bak` will take a backup from input file first.

Comment: How can I make it overwrite the result?

Comment: @Manuel Hi please see updated answer.

Comment: Very good. Worked great!

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^>/ { printf "%s ",$0; next; } { print; }' file1 | 
    sort -n |
    awk '{ print $1; print $2; }'
```

Comment: Nice.  Do you know of a good awk reference manual? And/or can you explain how the `'/^>/ { printf "%s ",$0; next; } { print; }'` command works?  Thanks.  I seriously have read about half of this manual and I think I need to read it about 2 more times after I finish before it sinks in:  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: I cannot recommend anything. I am not familiar with the available tutorials. I just read the man page (quite often) when I started using awk. I doubt that there is any tutorial which you would have to read only once... (unless it comes with tons of "homework"). The `/^>...` is simple: It selects every other line (you could do the same with the modulo 2 value of NR). The `>` lines shall become the first part of the resulting lines. Thus we may not print a newline at the end (which `print` does). The `next` reads the next line and prevents the `{ print; }` block from being executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Schwartzian` transform in `Perl` to do this:

```
perl -ne '
   push @A, $_.=<>}{
   print for
    # Schwartzian transform
    map  { $_->[0] }             # recover the line
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } # do the sorting using the key 
    map  { [$_,/_(\d+)M$/m] }    # setup: line(zeroth-indexed) + sorting key(first index)
    @A;                          # operate on elements of array @A
' yourfile
```

---

## Results

```
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_53M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_54M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_55M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_57M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_58M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_59M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_60M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_61M
.....................................
>nexus0013_Pseudomonas_62M
.....................................
```

---

stuff the file in line pairs into the array `@A`. Then at the eof, we perform the `Schwartzian` maneuver, `map->sort->map'. In this we carry the whole line + the sorting data along and in the last step of the maneuver, recover the line after it's been sorted. So for this case, the sorting key is the number before the M which lies at the line boundary. (Remember we appended the next line)